# Difference between $stateProvider.state().state(); and $stateProvider.state(); $stateProvider.state();

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I am confused about state method of $stateProvider.

what is difference between:

```
$stateProvider.state("home", {
  ...
}).state("aboutus", {
  ...
})
```

or

```
$stateProvider.state("home", {
   ...
});

$stateProvider.state("aboutus", {
   ...
});
```

Comment: There is no functional difference between these two methods of state registration

Comment: no real difference ... chained vs unchained

Comment: is any effect in memory management?

Comment: I prefer chained for readability and less duplication.

Comment: thanks all. but i make some new for my project. because my project have much more state. I think over 50 and state are randomly use. so how i decided to be use json format for ui.router. I make some new for this. my problem is : 

    `angular.forEach(routeJson, function(key, value){
$stateProvider.state(key.toString(), {
    ...
 });})`

so every time use $stateProvider. but how to make this format like:
 `angular.forEach(routeJson, function(key, value){
      state(key.toString(), {
        ...
      });
    })`

only first time use $stateProvider and after only append **.child()** method

Comment: you can't do the chain in a loop. As for memory...it's the same object reference so that isn't an issue.

Comment: ok thanks. your meaning **.state()** method return $stateProvider reference.